# Redirect to CMS page after logging in

Tags: redirect

On my webshop I don't want the customers to use the customer dashboard. 
I'm looking for a simple way(for a non-developer) to redirect to a custom CMS page.

Therefore when the customers signs in I want to transfer them to a page named employee-logged-in.html.
Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, the only thing Magento does by default is to redirect the user to the previous page or to the customer dashboard. This setting is in Admin->System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Login Options->Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in.

If you want something else but you're not a developer, use an extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-redirect-after-login-1.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-login-redirect.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-login-redirect-pro.html

Answer (score 0):

Overide magento magento customer Accountcontroller.php using 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350044/magento-overriding-customer-account-controller

```
then copy loginPostAction  function to your Accountcontroller.php
```

then goto loginPostAction function comment

```
  //remove from logidpost function
     $this->_loginPostRedirect(); 
add this function add 
     $this->_redirect('customcmspage');
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a builtin functionality to let you specify WHERE you should be redirected after the login.
Please read this [link](http://www.drewgillson.com/blog/magento-redirect-page-newsletter-subscription/)
You should set the Admin->System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Login Options->Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard to NO
and then in the login form add an hidden input field named "referer_url"

```
...
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.login.extra')?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
    **<input type="hidden" name="referer_url" value="employee-logged-in.html"/>**
    <div class="col2-set">
...
```

the code above was from default template/customer/login.phtml
you shoudl be able to modifiy it even if you are not a "programmer".